# Populating a list with table data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using entity and have created a table.

```
namespace TestExample {

 public class Blog
 {
  public int BlogId {get; set; }
  public String Title {get; set;}
  public String Description {get; set;}

  public virtual Blog Blogs {get; set;}
 }

 public class BloggingContext : DbContext
 {
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
 }

 class Program 
 {
  static void Main (string[] args) {
        var db = new BloggingContext()
        // Display all Blogs from the database
        var query = (from b in db.Blogs
                    orderby b.Title
                    select b).ToList();


        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            //
        }
 }
}
```

How would I go about populating a listbox with the entire table? When I try Listbox.Datasource = query; I get strange results. Is there another way than going through each item and printing out item.Title, item.Description etc?

EDIT: Its a winforms application.

Comment: winform or wpf.  you need to clarify because it changes a lot

Comment: If you use wpf/silverlight then you have to use ObservalbeCollection<youclass> as a property type, after in a xaml file you bind the property to a control. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625767/passing-data-from-2d-array-to-a-datagrid-wpf-c-sharp/19626081#19626081

Comment: Its a Winforms application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below line of code to add new item..

```
var query = (from b in db.Blogs
                orderby b.Title
                select b.Title).ToList();

foreach (var item in query)
        {
            mylistbox.items.add(item );
        }
```

Comment: I am still getting the same message which is system.data.entity.dynamicproxies.Blog_45.... instead of the data.

Comment: i uopdated the answer..try this if u getting atleast title in the list box?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are looking for asp.net application,windows forms or wpf. So I have given all three options. For asp.net application following is code for that.

```
listBox.DataSource=query;
listBox.DataTextField  = "Title";
listBox.DataValueField = "BlogId";
listBox.DataBind();
```

If you are using windows forms, you can use like following.

```
listBox.DataSource = query;
listBox.DisplayMember   = "Title";
listBox.DataBind();
```

See following link for windows forms for more information 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w67sdsex(v=vs.90).aspx

For WPF- Please go through following links.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c9b7b7a5-d9c0-4c6c-afcc-9b382991fd8a/how-to-bind-a-generic-list-to-a-wpf-listview?forum=wpf

http://dotprogramming.blogspot.in/2013/09/how-to-bind-listview-with-string-list.html

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/DataBinding10042007165025PM/DataBinding.aspx

Hope that will help you. You can also doing adding items via forloop as suggested in above answer.