# Load from XML to Observable collection

Tags: c#, xml, observablecollection

I am having trouble while load xml file into Observable Collection.

My XML look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Stock>
  <Assortment>
    <Item>Адельфан -  эзидрекс  таб  №10</Item>
    <Quantity>89</Quantity>
    <Price>3.0000</Price>
    <Summ>267</Summ>
    <Price1>3.0000</Price1>
    <Summ1>267</Summ1>
    <ValidDate>01.01.2031</ValidDate>
    <Manufacturer>КРКА</Manufacturer>
  </Assortment>
  <Assortment>
    <Item>Адельфан -  эзидрекс  таб  №10</Item>
    <Quantity>8</Quantity>
    <Price>3.0000</Price>
    <Summ>24</Summ>
    <Price1>3.0000</Price1>
    <Summ1>24</Summ1>
    <ValidDate>01.01.2019</ValidDate>
    <Manufacturer>КРКА</Manufacturer>
  </Assortment>
</Stock>
```

And my code which I tried is this.

```
            XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(filename);
                foreach (XElement xe in xml.Elements("Assortment"))
                {
                    _dummyCollection1.Add(new DummyClass1()
                    {
                        Наименование = xe.Element("Item").Value,
                        Количество = xe.Element("Quantity").Value,
                        Цена = xe.Element("Price").Value,
                        Сумма = xe.Element("Summ").Value,
                        Цена1 = xe.Element("Price1").Value,
                        Сумма1 = xe.Element("Summ1").Value,
                        Срокгодности = xe.Element("ValidDate").Value,
                        Производитель = xe.Element("Manufacturer").Value
                    });
                }
                BuyDataGrid.ItemsSource = _dummyCollection1;
```

I am getting empty DataGrid. How to pass xml in to Observable Collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to do it, in case if someone need;

```
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(filename);
                    XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
                    XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("Assortment"); 
                    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                    {
                        _dummyCollection1.Add(new DummyClass1()
                        {
                            Наименование = node["Item"].InnerText,
                            Количество = node["Quantity"].InnerText,
                            Цена = node["Price"].InnerText,
                            Сумма = node["Summ"].InnerText,
                            Цена1 = node["Price1"].InnerText,
                            Сумма1 = node["Summ1"].InnerText,
                            Срокгодности = node["ValidDate"].InnerText,
                            Производитель = node["Manufacturer"].InnerText
                        });
                    }
                    BuyDataGrid.ItemsSource = _dummyCollection1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class which you plan to use as an object for the ObservableCollection collection must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

this is my answer with an example how to populate model for dataGrid

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625767/passing-data-from-2d-array-to-a-datagrid-wpf-c-sharp/19626081#19626081)